# Uploading 8,5MB file using Laravel & Laravel Homestead

Tags: php, file-upload, laravel

I'm using Homestead locally to develop a bookstore and my client needs to upload a CSV file, the only thing is it's 8.5MB and it tried to upload it and extract the DB but after a minute or so it shows   `problem loading page`

My question is, is there a quicker way to do this to speed up the upload process for such a big file or are there some settings within Homestead I can alter to allow for this?

I've added

```
ini_set('upload_max_filesize', '20M');
ini_set('post_max_size', '20M');
ini_set("memory_limit", '256M');
```

to my controller but still no joy because of the size of the file, is there any way to enable this?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the max execution time of the script?

Comment: Like so ````set_time_limit(0);```` ??

Comment: Yes, that's correct [please read this page for important information, however](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: Yes tried that just now but still no joy!

Comment: Then we need further information as `problem loading page` isn't enough to go on.

Comment: Please see - http://cl.ly/image/2x153k0L2U2S

Comment: That's not enough. Check the error logs on the server.

Comment: Not sure how to check the logs with Laravel Homestead.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/62047/discussion-between-ohgodwhy-and-the-unforgiven-ii).